# If parent process change disposition of signal after child process excute, the child process affected by it?

Tags: unix, signals

I read a book about unix system programming.
There is code to ignore signal.
[image]

If the child run first and parent change its disposition of signal, then  ,is child affected by this changing? I'm korean. I'm not good at english. So I think there are grammar errors in my sentence. I just want to know whether child process affected by parent's changing disposition of signal when the parent's code of change of disposition were separated from child. And Do I have to writing the source of code? I don't know about american law. This book's name is Advanced Programming in Unix Environment Third edition by W. Richard Stevens and Stephan A. Rago. and page 370.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If parent changes its signal handling after forking a child, it does not affect the child.